# ZeroClipboard not working in a rails app (flash bridge error), works locally, off rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to use [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard) in a Rails project, and while the `ZeroClipboard.min.js` and `ZeroClipboard.swf` load just fine, when I hover over the `div` the  Flash movie is attached to, I get this error (and nothing works).

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'setSize'`

I'm using, copy-pasted, the example on the GitHub page, plus setting the movie path epath explicitly:

```
  <html>
  <body>
    <div id="d_clip_button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" title="Click to copy." style="border:1px solid black; padding:20px;">Copy To Clipboard</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/lib/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath("/assets/lib/ZeroClipboard.swf");
      var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client('#d_clip_button');
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This works if I run this form a non-Rails server, but when I run it either locally or on my remote staging server, I get the above error.

Any ideas?

Comment: How sure are you that it's loading the js file?  The error message is referring to a function (setSize) that's defined inside that file.  Can you post a link to your staging server (or anywhere we can see the error in action)?

Comment: My server logs indicate that the file was successfully served, and when I go to the URI of the js file directly, I can download the file. Is there something else I should be looking out for?

Comment: I would use Firebug in Firefox or the Inspector tools in Chrome/Safari to see the network request and verify that the js file was loaded.  If you have a public page where the error is happening, I can take a look.

Comment: http://cl.ly/Lp1B <- shows it is all being loaded,
http://cl.ly/LoBo <- shows the error (thank you for your help!)

Comment: Do you have a publicly accessible page with the problem?  I agree that the js is loading based on those screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this error when using ZeroClipboard with Turbolinks. I was able to work around it by adding:

```
$(document).on "page:before-change", ->
  ZeroClipboard.destroy()
```

to `application.js.coffee`. YMMV.